# Powershell Get-scheduledtask - query values for Monthly tasks and months / days task runs

Tags: powershell

I'm hoping someone can assist with this query.  I'm using a combination of Powershell's get-scheduledtask and get-scheduledtaskinfo combined with extended properties of .action and .triggers  and it gives me most of the info I wish to extract (task name, path, execution file, repetition, duration etc), however finding the values highlighted below is eluding me.

[image: GUI Task setting]

I'm hoping I have missed something simple and am digging deeper than I need to.  Can anyone advise of the powershell cmdlet to get the details that the job runs monthly, which months are selected and the day of the month the task will run?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further into this I'm not sure it is possible with native Powershell but found a suitable solution using:

```
schtasks /query /fo csv /v /tn \| convertfrom-csv | Select TaskName, "Last Run Time", "Next Run Time", "Task to run", Author, days, months, "Repeat: Every", @{N=’Creation Date’; E={$_."Start date"}} | export-csv c:\tmp\tasks.csv
```